# Membership Signup Form - add "Phone Number" field (required)

Tags: wordpress, civimember, forms

For this membership signup page:

https://connectionpractice.org/membership/

I want to add "Phone Number" as a required field for people signing up for a membership.

I can't find where I can configure the fields for the payment section.

I tried going to **Contributions > Manage Contribution Pages**

I do find this page there, and I was hoping to find a tab where I could configure these fields, but I don't see anything like that.

Have also gone to **Administer > CiviMember** but didn't find anything relevant there.

The payment gateway is Click & Pledge. I also looked at this item there, but don't see a place to configure these fields there either.

WordPress 4.8.1

CiviCRM 4.7.21

Any hints will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to add a new field, you would create a Custom Field in a Custom Data Set (civicrm/admin/custom/group?reset=1) and then add it to whatever Profile (/civicrm/admin/uf/group?reset=1) you're using for your page (which you'll find by editing the appropriate Contribution Page and looking for the profiles that are included). You can make the field mandatory in the profile.

The Phone Number field is part of Civi's Core functionality, so you just need to add it to the Profile. (Note: it's associated with Contact records).

There's already a lot of good documentation on this. You might want to start here: 
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/

Good luck!

Comment: Phone number is a CiviCRM Core field - so no need to make a Custom field; Add the Core Phone Number field to the e.g. Name & Address profile and then expose that Name & Address profile on your Contribution Page.

Comment: Concur with Karin. Pls edit your answer to make it clear that no Custom Field needs creating.

Comment: Thank you!  No custom field was required, just exposing the profile with the core phone number field.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Rowan's answer, go to Administer>Customize data and Screens>Profiles and choose the profile that is being used in your Contribution Page.  On the right hand side of that screen you will see a button called "Fields".  On clicking that button you will be taken to a page called Profile Fields where there is another button called "Add Field".   Select the type of CiviCRM record and the field you want to include in this Profile ("Phone" is an option under "Contacts" and you can make it required).

Voila!  Hope it helps.